# How to spy Save As in blue prism?

Tags: blueprism

How do I spy the Save As button. I have spy the arrow to click Save. Then I apply the Global send key Down and Enter. But when I run it, it will go to Save. How do I spy the Save As? Or any other advice?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Global Send Keys **Events** on the **top-level element** (Internet Explorer), and not the button element.